# submitting to packagist.org: package name problems or maybe http url problems

Tags: php, composer-php, packagist

I am trying to submit my package to packagist.org. The url of my repository:
https://seekquarry.com/git/yioop.git
when I try to submit it, packagist gives me a bunch of exceptions related to ssl, so I tried submitting without ssl using the url above but with http rather than https.
I am wondering if packagist can handle http-based repositories? This either
times out with a message that there is a problem on packagist's end or a complaint that my composer.json doesn't have a package name. However, my composer.json does have a package name on the master (and only) branch.
I have also used my repository with composer in other projects where I explicitly mention my repository. I would assume packagist is just using composer on the back-end. I was wondering if anyone could look at that url to see if there is anything missing from my composer.json or tell me if packagist accepts http-based repositories? I don't want to put my repository on github, I want to continue to host it where it is

Comment: The issue seems to be that my repository was slow to download to packagist. I did a git gc on my bare repository and then things worked.